# How do I call a function inside a for loop and write the return on another dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, jupyter-notebook

| Domain | plaintPDP |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 25frozen |
| NaN | azerty |

The above is one line of my dataframe.

I want to iterate through '**plaintPDP**' column using the following password_complexity function to give an index from 1 to 5 to a new column in the same dataframe called '**strenght**'

```
def password_complexity(password):
    if all(x.islower() for x in password):
        return 1
    elif all(x.islower() or x.isupper() for x in password):
        return 2
    elif all(x.islower() or x.isdigit() for x in password):
        return 3
    elif all(x.islower() or x.isupper() or x.isdigit() for x in password):
        return 4
    elif any(x.islower() or x.isupper() or x.isdigit() or x in string.punctuation for x in password):
        return 5
    else:
        return 0
```

i tried the following to fill the new column but the strenght column gets always 1

```
data9=FinalData["plaintPDP"]

for i in data9:
  FinalData[j] = password_complexity(i)
```

Comment: `j` is not defined in your code

Comment: sorry, it's just a mistake. I meant  FinalData["strenght"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iteratively inserting into a dataframe use the following one-line approach to fill the needed column (apply once):

```
FinalData['stregth'] = FinalData['plaintPDP'].apply(password_complexity)
```

---

```
  Domain  plaintPDP  stregth
0    NaN   25frozen        3
1    NaN     azerty        1
```